# Make geom_smooth() from ggplot2 adapt to number of observations

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make the `method` argument of `geom_smooth()` from `ggplot` be dynamic and adapt to the number of data points in a group?

For example, I have data in the following format:

```
1. DATE PRODUCT SIZE
2. 3/1/2017 A 10
3. 3/2/2017 B 14
4. 3/3/2017 C 25
5. 3/4/2017 A 16
6. etc.
```

This charts completely fine and adds a loess fit to each group (`PRODUCT`) with the following code (each `PRODUCT` group has about 20 entries):

```
DT<-read.csv("TEST_DATA.csv")

DT$DATE<-as.Date(DT$DATE, "%m/%d/%Y")

myPlot<-ggplot(DT, aes(DATE, SIZE, color = PRODUCT))

myPlot + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE)
```

However, let's say I add in just 2 data points for a 4th Product "`D`". I then get the following warning messages and no loess fit lines are added to the plot for ANY group.

```
Warning messages:
1: In simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  ... : span too small.   fewer data values than degrees of freedom.
```

I believe this warning is due to the fact that the number of observations for product `D` is less that the degrees of freedom for the loess fit.

Setting `method = "auto"`, chooses `"loess"` anyway so that doesn't help and setting method to `"lm"` is not what I want.

I would like to do the following but can't quite get it to work and am wondering if someone can help?

```
myPlot + geom_point() + geom_smooth(data = DT, method = if(length(DT$PRODUCT)<5) {"lm"} else {"loess"}, se = F)
```

As you can see, I am trying to have `geom_smooth()` use `method = "lm"` if any groups have less than 5 observations, otherwise use the `"loess"` method. But I can't quite figure out how to access the number of observations of each group within the `geom_smooth()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an `n` argument (number of points to evaluate smoother at) that you can use. See `stat_smooth` for details.

**EDIT:**
You can build the plot dynamically:

```
sProduct <- unique(DT$PRODUCT)
myPlot <- ggplot(DT, aes(DATE, SIZE, color = PRODUCT)) + geom_point()

for (i in sProduct){

  sMethod <- ifelse(sum(DT$PRODUCT == i) <= 5, "lm", "loess")
  myPlot <- myPlot + geom_smooth(data = subset(DT, PRODUCT == i), method = sMethod, se = FALSE)
}

myPlot
```

Comment: Hi Constantinos, thanks for you reply -  it seems the n option just decides how many resolution points it uses to plot the loess fit but this does not relate to the number of underlying observations. I'd like to use an "lm" fit when I have 5 observations or less, otherwise use "loess".

Comment: Hi Constantinos, this does exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that chooses the smoothing method conditionally, based on minimum group length. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_classic())

conditional_smooth = function(data, xvar, yvar, group) {

  p = ggplot(data, aes_string(xvar, yvar, colour=group)) + 
    geom_point()

  min_group_length = split(data, data[, group]) %>% map_dbl(nrow) %>% min

  # Choose smoothing method based on minimum group length
  if(min_group_length >= 5) {
    p + geom_smooth(method=loess) 
  }
  else {
    p + geom_smooth(method=lm)
  }

}
```

Let's run the function. For the `iris` data frame, the smallest group has length 50.

```
conditional_smooth(iris, "Petal.Length", "Sepal.Length", "Species")
```

[image]

Now let's shorten one group to four values:

```
conditional_smooth(iris[c(1:50,97:150), ], "Petal.Length", "Sepal.Length", "Species")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi eipi10, similar to Constantinos answer your answer also does exactly what I need. Thank you for your helpful and clearly portrayed solution!